# Add breakpoint in sass mixin

Tags: css, sass, responsive, font-size, scss-mixins

My end objective is to have 1 font size for mobile (16px) and another for desktop(18px), however I used this mixin to control the font-size. How can I adapt the mixin to acheive this. to save me having two versions of the mixin:

```
@mixin font-size($size) {
  font-size: $size;
  font-size: calculateRem($size);
}

@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / $font-size-root;
  @return $remSize * 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Why not putting a media querie in your mixin?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a media query in the mixin:

```
@mixin font-size($desktopSize, $mobileSize) {
  font-size: $desktopSize;
  font-size: calculateRem($desktopSize);

  // This is just and example mobile width
 @media only screen and (max-width:639px){
    font-size: $mobileSize;
    font-size: calculateRem($mobileSize);
  }
}

@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / $font-size-root;
  @return $remSize * 1rem;
}
```

You can further update the mixin parameters by setting the `$mobileSize` to equal the `$desktopSize`:

`@mixin font-size($desktopSize, $mobileSize:$desktopSize)`

This will prevent going through all the places in your code where you have used that mixin with a single parameter.